# Ext.dom is undefined Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have been developing on sencha touch for quite a while now, I was using an older CMD version till few months back and it was all good but as soon as i advanced to Sencha CMD 4.0.2.67  I have weird error that I had never seen, I developed the whole application all this while and ran on browser without any issues, but after packaging it, It says

```
Ext.dom is undefined app.js:1
```

The above error shows up in Console in Inspect Element. I tried removing every possible external library but it wouldn't solve it but then I thought why not generate a new app by sencha touch and try packaging it so that will clear my doubts about my code or its sencha? I generated a new app with this command:

```
sencha generate app TestApp C:/wamp/www/sencha/TestApp
```

After successful packaging I packaged it without changing anything with this code:

```
sencha app build package
```

After packaging and running it, the same error occurs as above! Is this a bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its a bug, Go back to the older sencha cmd version which can be found here:

[Sencha CMD 4.0.0.126](http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/beta/4.0.0.126/release-notes.html)

Generate a latest app and move over your views etc to the new app created by this cmd.